# How to control individual gstreamer pipelines when working with IPCPIPELINE and COMPOSITOR?

Tags: gstreamer

I am working on an application that can play 3 different videos. These videos should be displayed in a picture-in-picture view.
[pipeline presentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3JbR.jpg)
I selected GStreamer framework, and figured out that 'ipcpipeline' (to have split pipelines in the source process) and 'compositor' (to merge the stream from split pipelines, for picture-in-picture composition) would be useful.
I could write a code and it works fine, except the fact that changing state of one of the source pipeline (play/pause) changes the state of slave pipeline, and in turn changes state of every stream that slave is playing.
I know that with 'ipcpipeline', the master controls the state of the slave pipeline, but did not expect it this way.

I am wondering if there is any option using which truly independent control of pipeline can be achieved.
That means pausing the source pipeline 1 should not pause the all the videos in the slave pipeline.

Here is the source code that I have created.
It has a main function, that forks 3 child processes.
Each child process constructs a master pipeline to read from an MP4 file, parse it, and sink to ipcpipelinesink.
The parent process constructs a pipeline to receive from 3 master pipelines, and merge them using compositor and render using wayland sink.

It has a signal handler implemented, to be used with first child process only.
Whenever USR1 signal is triggered then the pipeline state in the first child process is toggled.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include "ipc_file_src.h"
#include "ipc_comp_sink.h"


void sig_usr1 (int signum)
{
    printf ("[%d] signal[%d] received\n", getpid(), signum);
    toggle_pipeline ();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int pid, pid1, pid2;
    int socks_ipc_src_1[2];
    int socks_ipc_src_2[2];
    int socks_ipc_src_3[2];

    if (socketpair (AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, socks_ipc_src_1))
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating sockets: %s\n", strerror (errno));
        return 1;
    }
    if (fcntl (socks_ipc_src_1[0], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) < 0 ||
            fcntl (socks_ipc_src_1[1], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) < 0)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error setting O_NONBLOCK on sockets: %s\n",
                strerror (errno));
        return 1;
    }

    if (socketpair (AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, socks_ipc_src_2))
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating sockets: %s\n", strerror (errno));
        return 1;
    }
    if (fcntl (socks_ipc_src_2[0], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) < 0 ||
            fcntl (socks_ipc_src_2[1], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) < 0)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error setting O_NONBLOCK on sockets: %s\n",
                strerror (errno));
        return 1;
    }

    if (socketpair (AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, socks_ipc_src_3))
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating sockets: %s\n", strerror (errno));
        return 1;
    }
    if (fcntl (socks_ipc_src_3[0], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) < 0 ||
            fcntl (socks_ipc_src_3[1], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) < 0)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error setting O_NONBLOCK on sockets: %s\n",
                strerror (errno));
        return 1;
    }

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // This is a child process and it will start a stream from a file
        printf("child[1] --> pid = %d and ppid = %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

        sleep (1);

        signal(SIGUSR1, sig_usr1);

        gst_init (&argc, &argv);
        create_ipc_source_1 ("video1.mp4", socks_ipc_src_1[0], socks_ipc_src_1[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        pid1 = fork();
        if (pid1 == 0)
        {
            // This is a child process and it will start a stream from a file
            printf("child[2] --> pid = %d and ppid = %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

            sleep (1);

            gst_init (&argc, &argv);
            create_ipc_source_1 ("video2.mp4", socks_ipc_src_2[0], socks_ipc_src_2[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            pid2 = fork();
            if (pid2 == 0)
            {
                // This is a child process and it will start a stream from a file
                printf("child[3] --> pid = %d and ppid = %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

                sleep(1);

                gst_init (&argc, &argv);
                create_ipc_source_1 ("video3.mp4", socks_ipc_src_3[0], socks_ipc_src_3[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                // This is a parent process and it will receive streams from child processes.
                // It will create a composition of input streams and display on the screen.
                printf("parent --> pid = %d\n", getpid());
                sleep (1);

                gst_init (&argc, &argv);
                create_ipc_sink (socks_ipc_src_1[1], socks_ipc_src_1[1],
                        socks_ipc_src_2[1], socks_ipc_src_2[1],
                        socks_ipc_src_3[1], socks_ipc_src_3[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>

static void demuxer_pad_added (GstElement *source, GstPad *newpad, gpointer *userdata);
static void error_cb (GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, gpointer *data);
static int state = 0;
static GstElement *pipeline;

void toggle_pipeline ()
{
    GstStateChange transition;
    if (state % 2)
    {
        transition = GST_STATE_PLAYING;
    }
    else
    {
        transition = GST_STATE_PAUSED;
    }

    state++;

    GstStateChangeReturn state_change = gst_element_set_state (pipeline, transition);
    printf ("[%d] Pipeline state set to [%d]\n", getpid (), transition);
}

int create_ipc_source_1 (gchar *filepath, int fdin, int fdout)
{
    int ret_val = 0;
    GstElement *filesource;
    GstElement *demuxer;
    GstElement *parser;
    GstElement *ipcpipelinesink;
    GstBus *bus;
    GstMessage *msg;

    filesource = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc", NULL);
    demuxer = gst_element_factory_make ("qtdemux", NULL);
    parser = gst_element_factory_make ("h264parse", NULL);
    ipcpipelinesink = gst_element_factory_make ("ipcpipelinesink", NULL);

    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new (NULL);

    if (!pipeline || !filesource || !demuxer || !parser)
    {
        printf ("[%d] Failed to create one or more element\n", getpid ());
        printf ("[%d] pipeline[%p] filesource[%p] demuxer[%p] parser[%p] ipcpipelinesink[%p]\n",
                getpid (), pipeline, filesource, demuxer, parser, ipcpipelinesink);
        ret_val = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("[%d] Pipeline and elements created\n", getpid ());

        g_object_set (filesource, "location", filepath, NULL);
        printf ("[%d] File source initialized [%s]\n", getpid (), filepath);

        g_object_set (ipcpipelinesink, "fdin", fdin, "fdout", fdout, NULL);
        printf ("[%d] Sockets assigned to ipcpipelinesink\n", getpid ());

        gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN(pipeline), filesource, demuxer, parser, ipcpipelinesink, NULL);
        printf ("[%d] Elements added to the pipeline\n", getpid ());

        if (((TRUE != gst_element_link (filesource, demuxer)) ||
                (TRUE != gst_element_link (parser, ipcpipelinesink))))
        {
            printf ("[%d] Failed to link one or more elements.\n", getpid ());
            ret_val = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("[%d] GStreamer initialized\n", getpid ());

            g_signal_connect (demuxer, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(demuxer_pad_added), parser);
            printf ("[%d] demuxer callback registered\n", getpid ());

            GstBus *bus;

            GMainLoop *loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);
            /* Instruct the bus to emit signals for each received message, and connect to the interesting signals */
            bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
            gst_bus_add_signal_watch (bus);
            g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus), "message::error", (GCallback)error_cb, loop);
            gst_object_unref (bus);

            GstStateChangeReturn state_change = gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
            printf ("[%d] Pipeline state set to Playing [%d]\n", getpid (), state_change);


            printf ("[%d] Starting the main loop\n", getpid ());
            g_main_loop_run (loop);
        }
    }

    return ret_val;
}

void demuxer_pad_added (GstElement *source, GstPad *newpad, gpointer *userdata)
{
    printf ("[%d] ******************************Demuxer \"pad added\" callback invoked\n", getpid ());
    printf ("[%d] Received new pad [%s] from [%s]:\n", getpid (), GST_PAD_NAME (newpad), GST_ELEMENT_NAME (source));

    GstElement *parser = (GstElement*)userdata;

    GstCaps *new_pad_caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps (newpad);
    GstStructure *new_pad_struct = gst_caps_get_structure (new_pad_caps, 0);
    const gchar *new_pad_type = gst_structure_get_name (new_pad_struct);

    printf ("[%d] new_pad_type[%s]\n", getpid (), new_pad_type);
    if (g_str_has_prefix (new_pad_type, "video/x-h264"))
    {
        printf ("[%d] it is video/x-264\n", getpid ());
        GstPad *parser_sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad (parser, "sink");
        GstPadLinkReturn ret;

        ret = gst_pad_link (newpad, parser_sink_pad);
        if (GST_PAD_LINK_FAILED (ret))
        {
            printf ("[%d] Type is '%s' but link failed.\n", getpid (), new_pad_type);
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("[%d] successful demuxer <-> parser\n", getpid ());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("[%d] it is not video/x-264\n", getpid ());
    }
}

/* This function is called when an error message is posted on the bus */
void error_cb (GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, gpointer *data)
{
    GError *err;
    gchar *debug_info;

    /* Print error details on the screen */
    gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &debug_info);
    g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
    g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
    g_clear_error (&err);
    g_free (debug_info);

    g_main_loop_quit ((GMainLoop*)data);
}
```

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/video/video.h>

int create_ipc_sink (int fdin1, int fdout1,
        int fdin2, int fdout2,
        int fdin3, int fdout3)
{
    int ret_val = 0;
    GstElement *ipcslavepipeline;
    GstElement *ipcsrc_1, *ipcsrc_2, *ipcsrc_3;
    GstElement *decoder_1, *decoder_2, *decoder_3;
    GstElement *compositor;
    GstElement *waylandsink;

    ipcslavepipeline = gst_element_factory_make ("ipcslavepipeline", NULL);

    ipcsrc_1 = gst_element_factory_make ("ipcpipelinesrc", NULL);
    ipcsrc_2 = gst_element_factory_make ("ipcpipelinesrc", NULL);
    ipcsrc_3 = gst_element_factory_make ("ipcpipelinesrc", NULL);

    decoder_1 = gst_element_factory_make ("avdec_h264", NULL);
    decoder_2 = gst_element_factory_make ("avdec_h264", NULL);
    decoder_3 = gst_element_factory_make ("avdec_h264", NULL);

    compositor = gst_element_factory_make ("compositor", NULL);

    waylandsink = gst_element_factory_make ("waylandsink", NULL);

    if (!ipcslavepipeline ||
            !ipcsrc_1 || !decoder_1 ||
            !ipcsrc_2 || !ipcsrc_3 ||
            !decoder_2 || !decoder_3 ||
            !compositor || !waylandsink)
    {
        printf ("[%d] Failed to create one or more element\n", getpid ());
        printf ("[%d] ipcslavepipeline[%p] "
                "ipcsrc_1[%p] ipcsrc_2[%p] ipcsrc_3[%p]"
                "decoder_1[%p] decoder_2[%p] decoder_3[%p]"
                "compositor[%p] waylandsink[%p]\n",
                getpid (), ipcslavepipeline,
                ipcsrc_1, ipcsrc_2, ipcsrc_3,
                decoder_1, decoder_2, decoder_3,
                compositor, waylandsink);
        ret_val = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("[%d] Pipeline and elements created\n", getpid ());

        g_object_set (ipcsrc_1, "fdin", fdin1, "fdout", fdout1, NULL);
        g_object_set (ipcsrc_2, "fdin", fdin2, "fdout", fdout2, NULL);
        g_object_set (ipcsrc_3, "fdin", fdin3, "fdout", fdout3, NULL);
        printf ("[%d] Sockets assigned to ipcpipelinesink\n", getpid ());

        gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN(ipcslavepipeline),
                ipcsrc_1, decoder_1,
                ipcsrc_2, decoder_2,
                ipcsrc_3, decoder_3,
                compositor, waylandsink, NULL);
        printf ("[%d] Elements added to the pipeline\n", getpid ());

        if ((TRUE != gst_element_link (ipcsrc_1, decoder_1)) ||
                (TRUE != gst_element_link (ipcsrc_2, decoder_2)) ||
                (TRUE != gst_element_link (ipcsrc_3, decoder_3)) ||
                (TRUE != gst_element_link (compositor, waylandsink)))
        {
            printf ("[%d] Failed to link one or more elements.\n", getpid ());
        }
        else
        {
            GstPad *comp_sink_pad_1 = gst_element_request_pad_simple (GST_ELEMENT (compositor), "sink_%u");
            GstPad *comp_sink_pad_2 = gst_element_request_pad_simple (GST_ELEMENT (compositor), "sink_%u");
            GstPad *comp_sink_pad_3 = gst_element_request_pad_simple (GST_ELEMENT (compositor), "sink_%u");

            GstStructure *converter_config = gst_structure_new ("GstVideoConverter",
                    GST_VIDEO_CONVERTER_OPT_THREADS, G_TYPE_UINT, 0,
                    GST_VIDEO_CONVERTER_OPT_RESAMPLER_METHOD, GST_TYPE_VIDEO_RESAMPLER_METHOD,
                    GST_VIDEO_RESAMPLER_METHOD_NEAREST, GST_VIDEO_CONVERTER_OPT_DEST_X,
                    G_TYPE_INT, 0, GST_VIDEO_CONVERTER_OPT_DEST_Y, G_TYPE_INT, 0,
                    GST_VIDEO_CONVERTER_OPT_DEST_WIDTH, G_TYPE_INT, 1400,
                    GST_VIDEO_CONVERTER_OPT_DEST_HEIGHT, G_TYPE_INT, 700, NULL);

            g_object_set (comp_sink_pad_1,
                    "xpos", 0, "ypos", 0,
                    "width", 1400, "height", 700,
                    "zorder", 0,
                    "converter-config", converter_config,
                    NULL);

            g_object_set (comp_sink_pad_2,
                    "xpos", 900, "ypos", 50,
                    "width", 340, "height", 240,
                    "zorder", 1,
                    "converter-config", converter_config,
                    NULL);

            g_object_set (comp_sink_pad_3,
                    "xpos", 900, "ypos", 400,
                    "width", 320, "height", 240,
                    "zorder", 1,
                    "converter-config", converter_config,
                    NULL);

            gst_structure_free (converter_config);

            GstPad *decoder_src_pad_1 = gst_element_get_static_pad (((GstElement*)decoder_1), "src");
            GstPad *decoder_src_pad_2 = gst_element_get_static_pad (((GstElement*)decoder_2), "src");
            GstPad *decoder_src_pad_3 = gst_element_get_static_pad (((GstElement*)decoder_3), "src");

            if (gst_pad_link (decoder_src_pad_1, comp_sink_pad_1) ||
                    gst_pad_link (decoder_src_pad_2, comp_sink_pad_2) ||
                    gst_pad_link (decoder_src_pad_3, comp_sink_pad_3))
            {
                printf ("[%d] failed to link\n", getpid ());
            }
            else
            {
                printf ("[%d] successful decoder <-> compositor\n", getpid ());
            }

            GMainLoop *loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);
            printf ("[%d] Starting the main loop\n", getpid ());
            g_main_loop_run (loop);
        }
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Why dont you try using `shmsrc` and `shmsink`. You can push your decoded frames  to a `shmsink` and another pipeline can pick up the `shmsrc`. You might have to add some check to see the validity of the shmsrc and then re-arrange the composite when one of the src is not available. I have used this method in the past to composite a PIP.

Comment: I started the implementation with a single process, that has one pipeline that does everything, including reading from 3 different sources (file, camera, and UPC), and compositing to display in PiP mode. The problem with this approach was that I could not control the seek/play/pause/stop operation for the file, specifically. I am relatively new to GStreamer, and exploring ways to de-couple the pipeline, and came across IPC pipeline. Thank you for your suggestion and I will try with shmsrc and shmsink options, and see how it works out.